# How do i store the secrets of my vue app in AWS lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I created a vue app with AWS authentication and I want to get any registered user credentials like email and password into a secret manager using AWS Lamba.
How do i go about it?

Comment: Why would you store the user password into the secret manager? Assuming the user is authenticated with AWS Cognito

Comment: The user is actually authenticated using aws Cognito but i did not save the password in secret manager. What i want to do is just create an enviroment variable using lambda function so i can deploy it to a secret manger tool

Answer (score 0):

To perform this use case, you can use the **AWS SDK For JavaScript V3**. You can use the Secrets Manager JS API from within an AWS Lambda function.

You can find examples of how to use the Secrets Manager JS API here:

https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/master/javascriptv3/example_code/secrets

If you are not familiar with how to use this API, refer to the DEV Guide:

[What's the AWS SDK for JavaScript?](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v3/developer-guide/welcome.html)

In this DEV Guide, you will also find information about **How To** create AWS Lambda functions:

[Creating and using Lambda functions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v3/developer-guide/lambda-create-table-example.html)